# Entity Framework not Saving Changes into Database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm puzzled as to why this code is not working, it should save changes to database after the loops but when I place the `SaveChanges` method inside the loop, it saves the record into the database but outside it doesn't save anything? it's about only 300 ~ 1000 records

```
    static bool lisReady = false;
    static bool sacclReady = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Logger("Starting services");
        ConnectDBLis().Wait();
        ConnectDBSaccl().Wait();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (lisReady & sacclReady){
            //start
            Logger("Services ready");
            StartExport().Wait();
        }
    }

    static async Task<bool> StartExport()
        {
            lis lisdb = new lis();
            nrlsaccl saccldb = new nrlsaccl();
            var getTestOrders = await lisdb.test_orders.ToListAsync();
            Logger("Services starting");
            foreach (var tO in getTestOrders.Where(x => x.entry_datetime.Value.Year == 2016))
            {
                foreach (var tr in tO.test_results)
                {
                    foreach (var tL in tr.test_result_logs)
                    {
                        results_availability postResults = new results_availability
                        { 
                          first_name = tO.patient_orders.patient.first_name,
                          middle_name = tO.patient_orders.patient.middle_name,
                          last_name = tO.patient_orders.patient.last_name,
                          birthdate = tO.patient_orders.patient.birthdate,
                        };
                        if (postResults.id == 0)
                        {
                            saccldb.results_availability.Add(postResults);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            saccldb.Entry(postResults).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            await saccldb.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
```

**Edit:**

So i limit the records to 100 and the save changes works, 3000 records at instant does not work, any solutions?

Comment: Is there any error while `savechangesasync`. I have replicated the above code in my local , it seems working fine for me

Comment: @Eldho i'm not getting any errors, i put a breakpoint on savechanges it hits it, can you show me your code?

Comment: Where could i post my code

Comment: @Eldho you can post it at pastebin

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SBaepLVT pls see the code

Comment: how many records are you inserting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109502/discussion-between-eldho-and-kevin-rodriguez).

Comment: i think your transaction will be rollback when the function is finished.

Comment: @MahdiFarhani why is that?

Comment: because saccldb  close before your query commited

Comment: right, @MahdiFarhani how can i solve that?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133801/entity-framework-6-async-operations-and-transcationscope

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't completely resolve your issue, this are some consideration for your problem.

*Note: This works for me when adding 1200 records and 300 modifications*

```
 static async Task<bool> StartExport()
    {
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            var appraisals = await db.Appraisals.ToListAsync();

            db.Database.CommandTimeout = 300;
            //Disabling auto detect changes enabled will bring some performance tweaks
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            foreach (var appraisal in appraisals.Where(g => g.Id > 1))
            {

                if (appraisal.Id == 10)
                {
                    appraisal.AppraisalName = "New name";
                    db.Entry(appraisal).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                else
                {
                    appraisal.AppraisalName = "Modified name";
                    db.Entry(appraisal).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }

            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

            if (await db.SaveChangesAsync() > 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

> You could use `db.Database.CommandTimeout = 300;` to increase the timeout of you connection.
>
> Entity framework 6 provides `AddRange()` This will insert the items in one shot, it will disable `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` and insert the entities

In your case you don't want to mark the entites as Modified, the EF already tracks it well. [Entity Framework - Why explicitly set entity state to modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7106211/1876572)

> The purpose of change tracking to find that you have changed a value on attached entity and put it to modified state. Setting state manually is important in case of detached entities (entities loaded without change tracking or created outside of the current context).

Here we have all entities attached to the context itself

Comment: I suspect there is something else is the issue. Using ef and above code i able to insert 3000 records. Use `SaveChanges` instead of `Aync` and look for the error its throwing

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
saccldb.SaveChanges()
```

Simply because the async nature of await saccldb.SaveChangesAsync() cause your thread to continue and exit the function before the saving to the db completes. In your case it returns true.

I would suggest not using any async operations on a console application unless it has a user interface that you would want to keep going.