# SaveChanges() doesn't insert any records to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to add new records to the database, everything goes ok without any errors, but I don't see the new record in the database.

Update code works, but insert code doesn't work. No errors appear, but no records are inserted into the database.

My code :

```
var DBs2 = ConnectionTools.OpenConn();
DBs2.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
DBs2.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

var resList = CreatedSerials.Where(u => u.Item4 == VID).ToList();

foreach (var r in resList)
{
    // if serial id ==0 => new then add it as new
    if ( r.Item7 == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var purchasesItemSerials = new purchases_item_seriels()
                                {
                                    pitem_ID = pitem_ID,
                                    stitems_ID = r.Item1,
                                    pmain_ID = PurchasesID,
                                    pitem_virtualID = r.Item4,
                                    pis_CustomSerial = r.Item2,
                                    pis_ExpireDate = r.Item3,
                                    pis_Statues = 0,
                                    ss_StoreID = Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(ItemImdex, "storeID")),
                                    Purchases_Price = Convert.ToDecimal(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(ItemImdex, "item_NetSmallestUnitPrice")),
                                };
            ss.Add(purchasesItemSerials);
        }
        catch (Exception eeeeee)
        {
            Msg.Show("", eeeeee.ToString(), 0);return;
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        var DBs350 = ConnectionTools.OpenConn();

        var UpdateSerial = DBs350.purchases_item_seriels.Find(r.Item7);

        UpdateSerial.pitem_ID = pitem_ID;
        UpdateSerial.stitems_ID = r.Item1;
        UpdateSerial. pmain_ID = PurchasesID;
        UpdateSerial.pitem_virtualID = r.Item4;
        UpdateSerial.pis_CustomSerial = r.Item2;
        UpdateSerial.pis_ExpireDate = r.Item3;
        UpdateSerial.pis_Statues = r.Item6;
        UpdateSerial.ss_StoreID = Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(ItemImdex, "storeID"));
        UpdateSerial.Purchases_Price = Convert.ToDecimal(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(ItemImdex, "item_NetSmallestUnitPrice"));

        DBs350.SaveChanges();
    }
}

try
{
    DBs2.purchases_item_seriels.AddRange(ss);
    DBs2.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception eeeeee)
{
    Msg.Show("", eeeeee.ToString(), 0);return;
}
```

**I also tried :**

```
DBs2.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
DBs2.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
```

but again: no data is inserted, no errors appear

**I also tried :**

```
int returnCode = DBs2.SaveChanges();
and returnCode = 0
```

**I also tried : inserting just a single item then SaveChanges **

```
// if this serial is new
                    var NewSerialresList = CreatedSerials.Where(u => u.Item4 == VID && u.Item7 == 0).ToList();
                    if (NewSerialresList.Count() > 0)
                    {

                        var ss = new List<purchases_item_seriels>();

                        foreach (var r in NewSerialresList)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                mrsalesdbEntities DBs002 = new mrsalesdbEntities();
                                var purchasesItemSerials = new purchases_item_seriels()
                                {
                                    pitem_ID = pitem_ID,
                                    stitems_ID = r.Item1,
                                    pmain_ID = PurchasesID,
                                    pitem_virtualID = r.Item4,
                                    pis_CustomSerial = r.Item2,
                                    pis_ExpireDate = r.Item3,
                                    pis_Statues = 0,
                                    ss_StoreID = Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(ItemImdex, "storeID")),
                                    Purchases_Price = Convert.ToDecimal(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(ItemImdex, "item_NetSmallestUnitPrice")),
                                };
                                //ss.Add(purchasesItemSerials);
                                DBs002.purchases_item_seriels.Add(purchasesItemSerials);
                                DBs002.SaveChanges();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Msg.Show("", ex.ToString(), 0);
                            }

                        }

                        int CC = ss.Count();

                    }
```

**i use this function to change the connection variables  at run-time :**

```
public static mrsalesdbEntities OpenConn()
        {
            mrsalesdbEntities MrSalesContext = new mrsalesdbEntities();
            MrSalesContext.ChangeDatabase
               (
                   initialCatalog: myconn.database,
                   port: Convert.ToUInt32( myconn.port),
                   userId: myconn.uid,
                   password: myconn.password,
                   dataSource: myconn.server
            );
            return MrSalesContext;
        }

public static void ChangeDatabase(
            this DbContext source,
            string initialCatalog = "",
            uint port = 3307,
            string dataSource = "",
            string userId = "",
            string password = "",
            bool integratedSecuity = true,
            string configConnectionStringName = "mrsalesdbEntities")
        /* this would be used if the
        *  connectionString name varied from 
        *  the base EF class name */
        {
            try
            {
                // use the const name if it's not null, otherwise
                // using the convention of connection string = EF contextname
                // grab the type name and we're done
                var configNameEf = string.IsNullOrEmpty(configConnectionStringName)
                    ? source.GetType().Name
                    : configConnectionStringName;

                // add a reference to System.Configuration
                var entityCnxStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
                    (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                        .ConnectionStrings[configNameEf].ConnectionString);

                // init the sqlbuilder with the full EF connectionstring cargo
                var sqlCnxStringBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
                    (entityCnxStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString);

                // only populate parameters with values if added
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(initialCatalog))
                    sqlCnxStringBuilder.Database = initialCatalog;
                if ((port) != 0)
                    sqlCnxStringBuilder.Port = port;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataSource))
                    sqlCnxStringBuilder.Server = dataSource;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
                    sqlCnxStringBuilder.UserID = userId;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                    sqlCnxStringBuilder.Password = password;

                // set the integrated security status
                //sqlCnxStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = integratedSecuity;

                // now flip the properties that were changed
                source.Database.Connection.ConnectionString
                    = sqlCnxStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // set log item if required
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does ss contain any items?

Comment: no 'ss' have 2 record ( count of the new records).

Comment: what happens if you would bypass using `ss` and just added to it directly to DB in the `foreach` loop. also: why are you using separate connections for insert and update? and to top that: why a separate connection PER item updated?

Comment: what happens if you would bypass using ss and just added to it directly to DB in the foreach loop.
(same issue)

Comment: The code as you've pasted it should work. My suspicions were around the disabling of AutoDetectChanges and ValidateOnSave, however tested against SQL Server, the code still inserts without issue. What Database engine are you connecting to?  Also, please put up the code for `ConnectionTools.OpenConn()`

Comment: i updated the question @StevePy

Comment: Hmm, still nothing standing out. What database? SQL Server, or something else?

Comment: database is MySQL @StevePy

Comment: How many items are being inserted in a single call? Have you tried inserting just a single item then SaveChanges? I can see there are issues reported with EF+MySQL with large numbers of inserts.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707696/entity-framework-not-saving-changes-into-database)

Comment: yes i tried that, and i get same issue , i will update my question to see the code ...

Comment: also i tried to insert many items (20,000) to MySQL with EF without any issue @StevePy

Comment: Your code would be much better if you removed all of the `catch (Exception ex)` code. Catching the top-level `Exception` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I did that.. @enigmativity

Comment: @BassemKamalM - Truly, really? You're not using that in your code any more?

Comment: I think I'll do the best to track the code correctly! @Enigmativity