# Revert the changes in database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, rollback

I am using SQL Server as my back end database and Entity Framework 6 to access it.

I want to undo all the changes done to the database by a method. The method makes several calls to 4 different databases and thus 4 different contexts. I am not able to keep track of changes to revert them at the end.

I am aware of `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` that keeps record of DB changes. But I am unable to utilize it because changes are lost as soon as a context goes out of scope. And I need need to revert the changes at the end of methods after accessing all 4 databases.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [transactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Transactions.TransactionScope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [beginTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx) you can get some basic information on both topics to get you started and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382892/database-begintransaction-vs-transactions-transactionscope) you can learn about the difference between them which will help you choose the right one for you.